# How to 'prioritise' a vanilla javascript if statement?

Tags: javascript, html

Currently experimenting for the first time with javascript. I'm trying to make a simple nav bar that disappears when the user scrolls down, reappears when they scroll up and does the same for when the mouse is in/out of the nav bar's area. Good news! Got that bit done.

The trouble comes when I then scroll up to make the nav bar appear, I move my mouse to click on it and then obviously a mouse event is triggered with the mouse outside of the `hotspot` and makes the nav bar disappear while you're on your way to it. It does reappear when I'm at the top with the mouse, but I'd like it to stay there once I've scrolled up to make it appear.

I have two if statements, one for the scroll and one for the mouse position. I'd like to make the site `prioritise` the effect of the scroll if statement over the mouse if statement.

This is the code I've stuck together after reading a hell of a lot of articles:

```
// Hide nav when scrolling down, show nav when scrolling up
var scrollCtrl = false;
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var prevScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    if (prevScrollPos > currentScrollPos) {
      navbar.classList.add('show');
      var scrollCtrl = true;
    } else {
      navbar.classList.remove('show');
      var scrollCtrl = false;
    }
  prevScrollPos = currentScrollPos;
}

// Get the height of the nav bar
var navHeight = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("navbar")).height;
navHeight = navHeight.substring(0, navHeight.length -2);
navHeight = parseInt(navHeight, 10);

// Show nav when mouse is at the top
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  var ypos = e.y;
  if (ypos <= navHeight && scrollCtrl == false) {
    navbar.classList.add('show')
  }
  else {
    navbar.classList.remove('show')
  }
});
```

What I've tried to do is use a boolean called `scrollCtrl` (because I want the scroll to be in control over the mouse position) but no matter what tweaks I make, I can't seem to get it to work.

The show/hide classes are just a CSS transform.

I am quite new to javascript, so please excuse any etiquette faux pas's!

Comment: Could be related to the issue: scrollCtrl exists in both global scope and function scope as two independent variables. You may want to put it global (remove var before scrollCtrl = true) so it is accessible from other functions

Comment: try the mouseout event instead of mousemove for hiding.

Comment: Eriks - nice spot. Hasn't worked unfortunately but the code is cleaner for it!

Comment: Garr - the mouseout event looks like the way to go! I'll just have to work on it a little

Comment: Unfortunately, mouseout isn't working :/